# Call dll function from matlab

Tags: matlab, dll, mcc

I have an m file from which I use to create dll using the Matlab deploytool. the code simply reads as:

```
function hello 
disp('Hello')
end
```

there are six functions in the compiled dll exported as:

```
uint8 helloInitialize
[uint8, voidPtr, voidPtr] helloInitializeWithHandlers(voidPtr, voidPtr)
helloPrintStackTrace
helloTerminate
uint8 mlfHello
[uint8, MATLAB arrayPtr, MATLAB arrayPtr] mlxHello(int32, MATLAB arrayPtr, int32, MATLAB arrayPtr)
```

Now I want to run this dll from my matlab command window using `calllib` and use
the `hello` function. Assuming that I use the correct function `mlfHello`, `calllib('hello','mlfHello')` gives me nothing. Please advise me on what function to call and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% its still the case but it certainly used to be that you couldn't load DLL's which were created in Matlab back into Matlab.

I suspect its still the case - so you cant do what your trying to do.

**[edit]** I dont have a link because they dont like to advertise the fact.  The reason AFAIK is to avoid users compiling toolbox capability into DLL and giving to others to use in Matlab without a toolbox license.

Comment: I'm confused. why is that? any reference to documentation?

Comment: I just checked the library by `libisloaded` and it gives me that it is loaded?

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me as the DLL has to load for Matlab to check.  As said I dont know if its the case in the latest version but it certainly was the case the llas time I tried/asked Mathworks (~2012b)